# mail() values not being sent

Tags: php

Here's a little problem for which I believe the answer is quite simple but maybe I cannot see the wood for the trees:

I have a form which displays data; the user is asked to edit the data which, in turn, updates the database and sends an email with the updated data. The email arrives but although it displays the titles does not display the data.

What am I doing wrong?

Text shown in email:

Name:
Email:
Phone:

php code:

```
$email_to = 'someone@here.com';
$name=$row['name'];
$email=$row['email'];
$phone=$row['mobtel'];
$email_subject = 'Feedback from website';
$headers = 'From: someone@there.com\r\n';

someone$message='Name:  ' .$name. "\r\n". 'Email:  ' .$email. "\r\n". 'Phone:  ' .$phone;


$sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);


 if($sent) 
 {print "Your mail was sent successfully"; }
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; }
```

This is the php code that preceeds the above:

```
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Unable to connect: " . mysql_error());

    if (isset($_GET['view']))
    {
    $user = sanitizeString($_GET['view']);




    $data = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE id='$user'";
    $result=mysql_query($data) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

?>

```
    <caption>Personal Record</caption>

<tr>
<th>ID</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['id'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Name</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['name'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>E-Mail</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['email'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Main Telephone</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['maintel'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Mobile Telephone</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['mobtel'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Organisation</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['organisation'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Group Leader</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['group_leader'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Supervisor</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['supervisor'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Volunteer</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['volunteer'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Assessor</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['assessor'];

        }
        }
     ?></td>
</tr>

</table>


    <br />
    <form method="post" action="update.php">
        <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Edit" style="width: 67px" /></form>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$row` contains values? Do a `var_dump($row)` then post the result. And also, they noted of your `someone$message`, should changed that to `$message`.

Comment: dqlopez  Here is the result of the var_dump: array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL } } . Obviously the $row is not picking up the value. Should I be better to use $_POST['value'] instead? And, 'Yes' the 'someone$message is a mis-copy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check your database connection and queries, probably the issue is in there.

Comment: @dqlopez: As I said, the database IS updated at the same time as the email is generated, as is the form displayed on the website so I know that the connection is working correctly and the query is producing the result I want.

Answer (score 2):

`someone$message` should probably be `$message`

Comment: This is a mis-copy - the actual line reads, $message. I don't know how the 'someone' got in front.

Comment: Yea no problem i only see what i read but anyway does it work now?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Please see my last comment to Rohit.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the someone$message in your sent;

Comment: @JonathonRomer: This is a mis-copy - the actual line reads, $message. I don't know how the 'someone' got in front.

Answer (score 0):

at first change this `someone$message` to `$message` then execute the code. Reason probably is that your array `$row` seems not having any value. Or to check `$row[]` use `print_r($row)`; :-)

Comment: Rohit Kumar Choudhary: Please see my comments above re 'someone'. As I said in my answer to @dplopez, as a result of his first suggestion, a var_dump shows that there are no values being populated into the message - but they are updating the database, It's a mystery to me...

Comment: please post your code what you have written before this $email_to = 'someone@here.com';

Comment: Hey hamish, your query seeems to give only one record, dont use while loop  instead of this just use it $row=mysql_fetch_array($result) and remove while and its braces. Your code will run.

Comment: Please accpet my answer dude :-) Glad to help you.